# Firestore Permission denied. Connecting firestore to react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
addPost = async ({ text, localUri }) => {
        const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri);

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.firestore
                .collection("posts")
                .add({
                    text,
                    uid: this.uid,
                    timestamp: this.timestamp,
                    image: remoteUri
                })
                .then(ref => {
                    res(ref);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    rej(error);
                });
        });
    };
```

And

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /posts/{doc} {
    allow read, write: if true;
  }
}
```

Above is my react-native code and below it is the firebase rules for my database so far.  Still getting

> FirebaseError:[code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Any help as to how to fix this code or to make my rules more secure?  At this point in the code the user has been authenticated.

Comment: hi check permission in fire base dashboard

Comment: Did you mean to say `cloud.firestore` instead of `firebase.storage`?  They are different products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules in the question are for firebase storage, you need to change the rule for firestore to `true`:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Check here for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules

Comment: any recommendations on where to find better documentation on how to link users to their posts with the rules.  Like im unsure if I I need to pass firestore more info or what.  And how to write the rules for that.